# Xrandr can't find display on other user

Tags: linux, monitor, xrandr

I'm running code to check if monitor is running. For one user xrandr works fine but for other not. In short, the code is like follows:

```
sys_call_return = execute_system_call("xrandr | grep connected");
std::size_t found_monitor_hdmi = sys_call_return.find("HDMI-1 connected");
```

If "HDMI-1 connected" is found, it asserts that monitor is working.

On: user@thispc it gives the list of connected HDMIs like expected.
On other user: test_user@thispc it gives "can't open display". It's needed to run on other user though. Any ideas how to allow other users to execute this?